# Get similar behavior between Clang and GCC for uninstantiated templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, clang++

GCC seems to be much more permissive regarding template code that is never instantiated than Clang is. I have a codebase that compiles without warning or error using `g++-5.1` (using `-Wall -Wextra -Wdeprecated -Wno-comment -Wnoexcept`), but emits many errors regarding template code using `clang++-3.7` unless I specify `-fdelayed-template-parsing`. The documentation on this flag is pretty scarce; all I can find is a [single sentence](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#microsoft-extensions) describing its behavior:

> `-fdelayed-template-parsing` lets clang delay parsing of function template definitions until the end of a translation unit.

Even this seems like it might be incorrect--I *think* the problem is that the templates are being parsed *at all*, and that the flag is actually allowing Clang to complete the compile without *ever* parsing the templates in question.

So I'd like to know:

1. How similar is the behavior of `-fdelayed-template-parsing` to the default behavior of GCC? The option itself is based on MSVC, which, as the flag-name implies, doesn't even check for basic syntax issues such as missing semicolons in uninstantiated template code. I believe GCC goes a little further than MSVC here, so does this flag actually make Clang *less* restrictive than GCC?
2. Going the other way, is there a way to make GCC behave more like Clang in this respect, by issuing an error, or at least a warning, for illegal code inside of uninstantiated templates?

**EDIT:** As requested, here's a trivial example of a template that (if not instantiated) does *not* cause an error with GCC but *does* cause an error with Clang:

```
template <typename T>
std::string neverInstantiated(void)
{
    return 3;
}
```

Obviously, since the template parameter is unused, this would be flagrantly incorrect regardless of how it is instantiated.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide an example that errors on clang but not on gcc?

Comment: If a template has no valid specialization then the program is ill-formed NDR. Both compilers are equally correct.

Comment: @Brian So what? My question isn't "which one is (more) compliant," it's "can I get similar behavior". And since GCC and MSVC both allow this, and Clang *can* allow this, there are large production codebases that make use of it, and therefore it's worth understanding even though the standard-based answer is "the program is ill-formed." This is why I did *not* ask about what the standard says.

Comment: @KyleStrand Well, there really is no point in making ill-formed programs compile (for now), is there?

Comment: @Barry I've provided an example, but in general it seems like GCC accepts almost any syntactically-valid code without name-resolution issues. I.e., the only errors I've seen it emit for uninstantiated templates are for syntax issues (e.g. the missing semicolon I mentioned) and when non-existent names (e.g. undeclared members) are referenced.

Comment: @Barry Actually, it appears that GCC also catches improper overloads, e.g. `void badOverload(void)` and `void badOverload(int i=3)`.

Comment: @KyleStrand (1) is trivial to anwser, clang does get less restrictive than gcc when you add `-fdelayed-template-parsing`, just remove the semicolon in your function template to prove that. For (2), why do you want to do this? If you're compiling with both gcc and clang, then use the latter's diagnostics to fix your ill-formed program.

Comment: @Columbo I'm really going to try to be matter-of-fact and non-snarky here. Legacy codebases exist. Production code (pretty solid and reasonably un-buggy production code, even!) exists with these "errors" in it. In fact, on Windows, `windows.h` (and by extension anything that includes it!) is technically non-standard-compliant. My intent is not to *write* ill-formed code; but I work in an environment that requires me to integrate my code with that of coworkers, 3rd-party library designers, etc, and some of *that* code is (technically) ill-formed. I *do* need this code to compile.

Comment: @Praetorian True--I suppose what I'd really like is to know exactly how permissive each compilation mode (clang with delayed parsing, GCC, and MSVC) is, but this may be difficult to characterize. For (2), yes, you're right, but I would really rather not need to rely on a separate compiler for this. (For instance, since GCC is our reference compiler, if I need to rebuild the toolchain(s) at some point, I might delay rebuilding Clang.)

Comment: @KyleStrand Alright, that sounds comprehensible. I thought that one could alter the templates in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @Columbo That would certainly be nice! Sadly, though.... http://mashable.com/2014/04/30/programming-sucks/

Answer (score 2):

From [temp.res]:

> If no valid specialization can be generated for a template, and that template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic
>   required.

So both compilers have valid behavior in this respect.

However, rather than trying to get clang to not issue a diagnostic, or trying to get GCC *to* issue one... I think it'd be better to take advantage of clang's additional diagnostic here and simply **delete** the ill-formed templates! Why would you want to pollute your codebase with invalid code anyway?

Comment: There are a couple reasons not to simply mass-delete the templates. One is simply that there are enough of them (...I did not write them...) that finding and deleting the unused ones would take a nontrivial amount of time, with not too much gained (since both compilers *can* compile with the improper templates present). Another is that it's not my code, and I don't think I am in a position to delete it (I'm not very experienced, etc). Finally, they is considered "potentially valuable", since the templates may be useful in the future (i.e. if we actually instantiate them at some point).

Comment: @KyleStrand Well, you *can't* instantiate them (that would be a hard error), so they can't very well be potentially valuable... ever.

Comment: Of course when we add code that instantiates them, we'd also fix the template code (for each template we actually instantiate). And if we happen to have time, we may start trying to fix the invalid code before we actually need it (YAGNI, but...well, it probably won't be my call), hence the desire for a diagnostic that's not a hard error.